# Ionic 3 - Released apk installed once but not able to install it again once uninstalled

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've posted a question in ionic forum[ionic 3 release apk](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-3-released-apk-installed-once-but-not-able-to-install-it-again-once-uninstalled/133796?u=heenavora)

Hello guys,
There is a problem with my released apk. The problem is that I generated one released apk with --prod --release command. The apk is installed once. I uninstalled it and tried to install again.Then it sticks in installing step on android and after few minutes it prompted that **app is not installed. reason : Other**.

Sometimes it shows that **google play protect identified an unknown developer**, sometimes it just passes the security permissions. Installed anyway is working fine for the first time. But second time it did not installed. I've **signed my apk** still it shows unknown developer.

I followed all the instructions as in ionic framework but no luck.

Can you please help me out? It will be really very very greatful. :slight_smile:

Here is my ionic info:

```

cli packages: (C:\Users\APP_02\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v8.9.0
npm               : 6.1.0
OS                : Windows 8.1
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\APP_02\android-sdks
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

```

Here is my platform info:

`Installed platforms:
  android 6.4.0
Available platforms:
  browser ~5.0.1
  ios ~4.5.4
  osx ~4.0.1
  windows ~5.0.0
  www ^3.12.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue I have faced for some few days but I have fixed using generate with new keystore file because my old keystore file is corrupted.

**Rebuild your app with new keystore file.**
It seems like your old keystore file is corrupted or torn.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same issue but with --prod command. I tried disabling the `Scanning device for security threats` in `play protect` in google play store.I hope it works for you.